# Braintree Drop in UI - add credit card

Tags: ios, braintree

Is there an option to just add a credit card to a User with the Braintree drop in UI, or can it only be used for a payment? I have my server configured to send tokens and receive payment, but I would like my Users to be able to add a credit card before using my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can't add credit card only.

As per my email communication with the Braintree support team, If you're using Drop-in Payment UI, then you can't add a credit card only. While doing any transaction only, users will be able to add a credit card.

Comment: Full Disclosure: I work at Braintree. When used with a customer ID, the Drop-In will [automatically vault any new cards the customer uses](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2#customer-id). If you want manual control over vaulting, you should use Braintree's [Hosted Fields product](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview/javascript/v3) instead.

Comment: @jake, using JS client, we can get payment method token and can save it against Braintree customer id  - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration. Is there any similar thing available in iOS client SDK?

Comment: @ArindamNayak, this deviates from the question a bit, so I encourage you to open a new question or to [reach out to Braintree support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact) if you need any follow-up. In short: Yes, the [iOS SDK returns payment method nonces](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/client-side/ios/v4) that you may use to store payment methods in your Braintree Vault.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a little bit tricky to figure out but I could do that using the components included in the Braintree SDK for iOs ( v. 4.9.0 )

You have to get a "token" from your server without the "customerId" ( this avoid to save the card automatically )

When you receive the "token" you can do this:

```
            NSString* token = [jsonData valueForKey:@"response"];
            self.req=[[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];

            self.req.applePayDisabled = YES ;

            self.cardForm = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:token request:self.req handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {



            }];

            BTCardFormViewController* vd = [[BTCardFormViewController alloc] initWithAPIClient:self.cardForm.apiClient request:self.cardForm.dropInRequest];
            vd.supportedCardTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@(BTUIKPaymentOptionTypeVisa)];
            vd.delegate = self;

            UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vd];
            if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
            }

            [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The code above will present the standard Braintree form to collect card data.

You have to implement the BTCardFormViewControllerDelegate to get the tokenized card.

```
- (void)cardTokenizationCompleted:(BTPaymentMethodNonce * _Nullable )tokenizedCard error:(NSError * _Nullable )error sender:(BTCardFormViewController *) sender;
```

Here you have access to the tokenized card and to the view controller with the card's data.

You can get the gateway configuration to display the supported card.

Hope can help.